# Applying substitution to multiple integral

Tags: integration, substitution

Let $f$ be an integrable function from $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}.$

I have the following integral $$I=\int_{-a}^a\int_{-a}^a\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x-y-z)dxdydz.$$

Is is possible to make a change of variable such that the integral will only depends on $(y,z)\;?$

I tried $(u,v,w)=(x,x-y,z)$ if I am not mistaken I have $$I=2a\int_{0}^{2a}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(y-z)dydz.$$ Is it correct ?

Comment: The integral over the whole domain is invariant under translations so $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x-a) dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) dx$ for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$, right? This should do the trick.

Comment: Just to be clear, which integration limits correspond to which variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try $(u,v,w)=(x,y,x-y-z)$. For $(x,y,z)\in[-a,a]\times[-a,a]\times\mathbb R$ you have $(u,v,w)\in[-a,a]\times[-a,a]\times\mathbb R$ and $|J|=|\frac{\partial(x,y,z)}{\partial(u,v,w)}|=1$, so $$\int_{-a}^a dx \int_{-a}^a dy \int_{-\infty}^\infty dz f(x-y-z) = \int_{-a}^a du \int_{-a}^a dv \int_{-\infty}^\infty dw f(w) = 4a^2 \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(w)dw $$

Comment: thanks but I want to keep $(y,z)$ as I want, my calculation is correct or not ?

Comment: @ViktorGlombik The jacobian. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant

Comment: @TTL Yes, your calculation is correct.